# Azure Partner Center VM from shared image gallery not available in any region

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I have trouble configuring my VM offer in the partner center. I have a shared image gallery with an image definion and version in it.
I provided it as a source for my vm offer.I selected all regions in plan overview > pricing and availability > marktes.

All tests pass and I want to crate a VM from the offer I created. But then the azure portal notifies me, that this vm offer is not available in my region.
How can this be? Do I have to configure the regions anywhere else?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem was a discrepancy in the naming.
There are some characters that cannot be used, but the wizard did not prohibit them from being entered. Hence the image could not be found.